# Excel VBA Copy multiple sheets into one sheet not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following vba:
Data is all text, Rows A - J with column headers on every sheet are the same
Data is sql queries all with "top 1000"
4 sheets (`sheet1`, `sheet2`, `sheet3`, `Master`)

sheet 1: 100 rows
sheet 2: 34 rows
sheet 3: 900 rows
Master: merged data from 3 sheets

PROBLEM: `Sheet3` only copies 84 rows specifically however adding more rows to other sheets will copy over to Master. Only `sheet3` will not copy more than 84 rows.

```
'   Step 1: Clear master before updating
'   Step 2 : Loop through the regional sheets

 Sub Consolidate()

    Dim cell            As Range
    Dim wks             As Worksheet

    Sheets("Master").Range("A2:Z65536").ClearContents

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wks.Name <> "Master" And wks.Range("A2") <> "" Then
        
            For Each cell In wks.Range(wks.Range("A2"), wks.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
                 cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Master").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Next cell
        End If
    Next wks
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the data starting in `Range(A2)` always populated?

The For Each cell In `wks.Range(wks.Range("A2"), wks.Range("A2").End(xlDown))` will start from `A2` and go to the last populated cell before a blank/empty cell.

Comment: I'm a bit new to vba, but if I understand correctly the Range("A2") is never null or empty. there's always data from A2:Jxxxx which needs to be populated into the master.

Thanks

Comment: I would check the data on sheet 3 to be sure that Range A2 onwards is always populated, can't see anything else that would cause the problem from your vba...especially if it works for other sheets

Comment: Yea that's interesting, sheet3 is populated from A2:J903. I thought maybe there's a size issue where the Range object or Worksheet object can't hold more than a certain number of rows. But obviously that's dumb and other sheets work fine with more data. 

I guess it's one of those mysteries because I can't think of anything else at this point. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: there was an empty cell at A843...guess I missed it. That was the solution. Thanks Cynicszm